# how to install gdal1.10.0 and solve the json_object error

Tags: gdal

system:ubuntu16.0.4
gdal:1.10.0

```
./configure
make
```

Error detail Information:

```
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
                 from /usr/local/src/gdal-1.10.0/port/cpl_port.h:147,
                 from /usr/local/src/gdal-1.10.0/port/cpl_conv.h:34,
                 from json_object.c:12:
json_object.c:29:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
   char* strndup(const char* str, size_t n);
         ^
GNUmakefile:23: recipe for target '../../o/json_object.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [../../o/json_object.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gdal-1.10.0/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/jsonc'
../../../GDALmake.opt:555: recipe for target 'jsonc-target' failed
make[3]: *** [jsonc-target] Error 2

make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gdal-1.10.0/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson'
../../GDALmake.opt:555: recipe for target 'geojson-target' failed
make[2]: *** [geojson-target] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gdal-1.10.0/ogr/ogrsf_frmts'
GNUmakefile:51: recipe for target 'sublibs' failed
make[1]: *** [sublibs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gdal-1.10.0/ogr'
GNUmakefile:56: recipe for target 'ogr-target' failed
make: *** [ogr-target] Error 2
```

I find this url,the problem is as same as I meet.
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Error-while-compiling-gdal-1-9-2-in-Ubuntu16-04-td5334012.html
I don't konw how to solve this problem,I had use google search it,but nothing to help.
Any Help will appreciated！

Comment: Finally I  give up，I use the latest version(2.4.0) then successed